# Are there any signs requiring side-to-side movement of fingers?

Tags: sign-languages, asl

Lately I've been thinking about the kinematics and [kinemes](https://www.yourdictionary.com/kineme) of ASL. For lack of better terminology, I'll use **"side-to-side"** to mean the movement one's finger makes when tilting it left or right (either *once/held* or wiggling *back and forth*; for example see [this GIF](https://giphy.com/gifs/ZaraLarsson-zara-larsson-shake-finger-wiggle-LnRjabvxYWfvVZ2B5Y)). Side-to-side is specifically in reference to the finger joint movement, not wrist or arm movement which moves a stationary finger. For the purpose of this question, the thumb is a finger as well.

My question is, are there any signs in ASL which use side-to-side movements of fingers? If so, which fingers and what signs?

Comment: That movement is usually called _wagging_ your finger. I don’t know any sign languages, but in spoken language (well, in English anyway) it’s usually used to indicate an often humorous reproach or rejection, often accompanied by a verbal /ʔaʔaʔaʔa/  or ‘no-no-no-no’.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet note that my question is both about wagging one's finger, and just holding the finger in that tilted position. Essentially just any deviation from vertical

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While contemplating this question I've come to a partial answer, mainly with regards to tilting fingers. If anyone can think of examples of signs with wagging any fingers (including the thumb), I encourage you to add that as an answer. :)

There are at least two situations I've thought of that require sideways finger movement. The first is the difference between handshapes "U" and "V":

["U" handshape](https://www.lifeprint.com/asl101/signjpegs/u/u.jpg) vs ["V" handshape](https://www.lifeprint.com/asl101/signjpegs/v/v.jpg)

There is also a tilting difference between the handshapes for "B" or "Classifier B" vs "5 hand":

["B" handshape](https://www.lifeprint.com/asl101/signjpegs/b/b1.jpg) or ["Classifier B" handshape](https://www.lifeprint.com/asl101/signjpegs/f/flat.jpg) vs ["5 hand" handshape](https://www.lifeprint.com/asl101/signjpegs/numbers/5.jpg)

(Source of images: https://www.lifeprint.com/asl101/pages-layout/handshapes.htm)